# tcl extract value from string

Tags: compare, tcl, extract

I have the following context:

```
Radio power mode = ON
Current Band = GSM 900, Channel Number = 63
Current RSSI = -95 dBm
Band Selected = Auto
Number of nearby cells = 1
Cell 1
        Primary Scrambling Code = 0x1C4
        RSCP = -115 dBm, ECIO = -16 dBm
```

I need extract the value from the line "Current RSSI", and check based on the list below:

```
- > -60 dBM = Solid
- <= –60 to 74 dBm = Very strong signal
- <= –75 to 89 dBm = Strong signal 
- <= –90 to 109 dBm = Fair signal
- <= –110 dBm = Unusable signal
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm) command to pull the number out of the string.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
regexp {Current RSSI = ([^ ]+)} $the_data match rssi
```

That will return `1` if the string was found, so you can use a conditional statement like this:

```
if {[regexp ...]} {
    # the match was found
    ...
}
```

Given your data, `rssi` should contain the string `"-95"`. You can then convert that to an integer and use it to compute the string.

Comment: Bryan, of regexp I get the following: "Current RSSI = -95".
How extract only the -95 ?
Thx!

Comment: @CFRR: my answer shows how. You put paremthesis around the part of the regular expression that you want to capture, and then specify a variable to hold that value.

Comment: I'm sorry but tcl/regexp is not specialty...

I have:

set command [ exec "show cellular 0 radio" ]
set current_rssi [ regexp {Current RSSI = ([^ ]+)} $command ] -> will return 1.
if {$current_rssi} {
 ?and now!? sorry
}

Comment: @CFRR: your regexp command is no the same as the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You populate two variables: 
- match which holds the total matching string, which is "Current RSSI = -95"
- rssi which contains just the substing enclosed in parenthesis in the regexp, which is -95.